# The classical definition for the $sign$ function does not interact well with complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, terminology

The classic definition for the sign function is [1]
$$sign(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{x}{|x|}, & \text{if } x \neq 0 \\
0, & \text{if } x = 0
\end{cases}$$
But when the $sign$ function is applied to the complex numbers you get a continuous function instead of the nice step like function that exists for the sign in the reals. Wouldn't it make more sense to use
$$f(a+bi)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{a}{|a|}+\frac{b}{|b|}i, & \text{if } a+bi \neq 0 \\
0, & \text {if } a+bi = 0\end{cases}$$?
[1] I didn't use the inequality definition of the sign function is because "inequalities are not well defined in the complex plane"/"the complex numbers are not well ordered".

Comment: I prefer the conventional definition.

Comment: Why? I honestly see it as useless.

Comment: @AaronQuitta How is the proposed definition any more useful? I'm a little puzzled as to how "sign" is supposed to make any sense in an unordered field. I usually think of it as indicating an orientation, something I'm accustomed of thinking about as discrete.

Comment: I'm a little confused on what you mean by orientation. Also, I realize its alittle weird to try to create sudo order in an unoreder field, but I feel that I generally is nice to have some order rather than none. Although no order is create. The problem is only really set back a step.

Comment: x=sign(x) |x| is useful in a vector space point of view, you have module and direction

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is a good fit for our format, either. The only question I see is "Would it make more sense to define sign on $\mathbb C$ this way", which is pretty subjective.

Comment: Could you give us an example where your proposed definition is _used_?

Comment: It is pretty subjective. You are correct on that. I was unaware of its uses for vectors and such.

Comment: There is no presented use, it was an off shoot idea. Then again, I can not think of many uses for the sign function in general.

Comment: "I can not think of many uses for the sign function in general." Oops, Heaviside is turning on himself in his grave...

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm unfamiliar

Comment: Oh, the step function? I don't see any uses for that either, Im sorry.

Comment: No use for the step function? You should say this to any physicist you know (but beware of their reaction...).

Comment: I meant in a pure math way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the original definition works perfectly for complex numbers. Except at $z=0$, it gives a unit direction vector for $z$, as is exactly the case for the reals. (We regard positive reals as "pointing to the right" and negative reals as "pointing to the left"; $0$ doesn't point anywhere.)

It coincides with the real version for real values of $z$.

It is NOT continuous at $z=0$, as is also the case with the reals. It is continuous everywhere else, as is also the case with the reals.

Seems pretty good to me.